# Modulo in order of operation

Tags: math, expression

Where does modulo come in the mathematical order of operation? I am guessing it is similar to division, but before or after?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This depends on the language, but in C style languages `%` is the same [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) as `*` and `/`. This means that if it appears in the same expression (without parentheses) the order depends on the [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). In this case `%` is usually left-associative, so the operators will be executed in left-to-right order.

Comment: a%b == ((a/b)-floor(a/b))*b  // Uses a combination of multiplication, division, subtraction, and floor function :o

Comment: What languages *don't* do this?

Comment: In javascript % executed first then * and /

Answer (score 44):

The relative precedence levels of operators found in many C-style languages are as follows:

[image: table]

[*Wikipedia - Order of Operations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages)

Answer (score 14):

At least in C++ and Java, modulo (`%`) has the same level of precedence as multiplication and division.

Since `%`, `/` and `*` are (usually) left-associative, they are evaluated left to right.

(Thanks to Mark for pointing out [operator associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity))

Comment: `In the absence of parentheses, operators of the same level of precedence are simply evaluated left to right.` Not always. See Operator Associativity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Answer (score 5):

If your question is about programming languages then yes, % has the same order as * and /

See [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages).

Comment: Nice to know most languages tend to follow the same standard.

Comment: I'd downvote if I could. The link could rot at any time at the whim of the wikipedia editors/ moderators. Meher's is way better.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator %, as used in many computer programming languages, is not common in pure mathematics. So it is rather a question of how the operator is treated in programming languages, and this differ between different langauges.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ it has the same precedence as multiplication and division.  Take them as they come, left to right.