# Modulo and order of operation in Python

Tags: python, modulo, operator-precedence

In Zed Shaw's [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org) (page 15-16), he has an example exercise

```
 100 - 25 * 3 % 4
```

the result is 97 (try it!)

I cannot see the order of operations that could do this..

100 - 25 = 75
3 % 4 = 0
or (100-25*3) =225 % 4 = ???   but anyhow not 97 I don't think...

A similar example is `3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6` which yields 7

In what order are the operations done?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary

Comment: You got even got the multiplication and subtraction wrong, they use the same order as in basic math.

Comment: He should have explained that. Again I'm sad to conclude that there are better Python tutorials. Try "Dive into Python".

Comment: wtf, `3%4 == 0`? does not even make sense, `3%4 == 3` ...

Comment: There is a more general version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3114145/78782

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For the first example: `*` and `%` take precedence over `-`, so we first evaluate `25 * 3 % 4`.  `*` and `%` have the same priority and associativity from left to right, so we evaluate from left to right, starting with `25 * 3`.  This yields `75`.  Now we evaluate `75 % 4`, yielding `3`.  Finally, `100 - 3` is `97`.

Comment: Thanks to all this, your answer and the ones that follow are very helpful, even the references, and I have most don't really make this clear, and the whole modulo concept is a bit alien to me..although I get it have never had the use case.(for modulo that is..)

Comment: a standard wall clock is "modulo 60" because once you get to 59 minutes, and add 1 minute, you get 0 (== 60)

Comment: The modulo is just the remainder of division. Knowing when to us it can be tricky, but the concept is rooted in basic math.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication >> mod >> subtraction

```
In [3]: 25 * 3
Out[3]: 75

In [4]: 75 % 4
Out[4]: 3

In [5]: 100 - 3
Out[5]: 97
```

Multiplication and modulo operator have the same precedence, so you evaluate from left to right for this example.

Comment: It's not only a question of what appears first.  For example `2**3**4 == 2**(3**4)`, because the associativity of `**` is right to left.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to your second question because it was bugging me too--Zac's response is close, but the loss of the result of 1/4 is because of Python 2.X is truncating integer division results. So it's evaluating the modulo operation first, then the division (which since it isn't float, is returned as 0.

```
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + (0) - (0) + 6 
6 - 5 + 6
1 + 6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it goes:

'*' and '%' have the same precendence, so evaluate those from left to right.

1. 25*3 = 75
2. 75 % 4 = 3 (4*18 = 72; remainder is 3)
3. 100 - 3 = 97

Q.E.D.

Comment: Not everything with the same precedence is evaluated from left to right -- e.g. `2**3**4 == 2**(3**4)` is evaluated from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Original problem: `100 - 25 * 3 % 4`

Actually, evaluating `25 * 3` and taking 75% of 4 is incorrect, and happened to work out conveniently for this problem.

What the % in python actually is is a modulus operator where x % y gives the remainder of `x / y`. In this case, what happened was that `75 / 4` is 18, with a remainder of 3, which is why `100 - 3 = 97`.

Do not try to multiply the percentages, it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In the second exampe, %has same order as * so we get 3+2+1-5+4%2-1/4+6=
3+2+1-5+(4%2)-(1/4)+6=1+(4%2)-(1/4)+6
=1+0-(1/4)+6=1-(1/4)+6=0.75+6=6.75 and that is what it says when I try it on the console, so whatever you did you must have done something to round it.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics isn't my strong point, so yes this question got me as well, for a moment. But hope you find this useful.

75 divided by 4 is 18.75

18 multiplied by 4 is 72 (leaving 3 remaining from the 75)

The calculation given is 100-25*3%4 with an answer of 97. Now this is how I would get it using PEMDAS as he speaks of in the question section:

```
#!/bin/python

A = 100
B = 25
C = 3
D = 4
E = B*C # 75
F = E%D # 3
G = A-F # 97
print("B * C ="), E
print("E % D ="), F
print("A - F ="), G
```

I think you have to treat modulo (%) as a division,

Answer (score 0):

Python evaluates % after * but before + or _ .

So,

```
(100 - 25 * 3 % 4)
(100 - 75 % 4)
(100 - 3) 
(97)
```